# UIView transform animation - scale and translate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

[image: 4 Categories]

[image]

I have 4 category views (they are rotated initially by `-M_PI/4`), and I want to zoom in one of them (let's say view2) to be the size of whole this part. Which means I need animation of transform property, where I should use translate and scale.
Just scale works fine, and I used:

```
let zoomTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(newCategoryView.transform, 2.5, 2.5)
```

But, translate itself doesn't work, then I plan to use them both with `CGAffineTransformConcat()`

I tried to translate with this:

```
let translateTransform:CGAffineTransform  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(newCategoryView.transform, newCategoryView.frame.origin.x - self.view.center.x, newCategoryView.frame.origin.y - self.view.center.y);
```

But somehow it does't respect old rotation and starts from weird position.

Comment: because the transform is relative to the rotation, try transforming only along one axis and look where the tile moves.

Comment: Tried transform by x only (y was 0) and it goes up. This is because rotation is 45 degrees on right.

Comment: is that what you want or not what you want? with "up" do you mean "straight up" or "up and left" (what I would expect)

Comment: It depends on the view. It should be on the center of the screen, from current location,